# how RANDOMX_CACHE_ACCESSES parameter increases at product of light mode

Tags: mining-technical-details

do really fast & light mode execute same code and how RANDOMX_CACHE_ACCESSES determines at product of light mode . how superscalar pipelines instruction & simulates vm. what is significance of RANDOMX_SUPERSCALAR_LATENCY. what is significans of superscalar function in rx. how this at product is maintained in light and fast mode.

Comment: at = area time here area means memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was answered at docs sorry

Comment: Can you please link to the relevant documentation that helped you?

Comment: https://github.com/tevador/RandomX/tree/master/doc has all the documents